# How do I make a loop until the user gives correct input in Java, if there's multiple 'correct' paths?

Tags: java, loops

I have a program that asks the user to input one of three options- DOMESTIC, STRAY, or CLAN
I'd like to make it so that it keeps asking for proper input if the user doesn't answer properly, until "pBackg" has either of the options.
I think I've seen how to do loops, but only for one specific value (example: loop until pBackg is DOMESTIC)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WanderingCats {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Please type your Cat's BACKGROUND!:");
        System.out.println("Your options are:");
        System.out.println("DOMESTIC / CLAN / STRAY");
        String pBackg = input.nextLine();
        
        
        switch(pBackg) {
        case "DOMESTIC":
            System.out.println("You're a DOMESTIC cat!");
            break;
        case "CLAN":
            System.out.println("You're a CLAN cat!");
            break;
        case "STRAY":
            System.out.println("You're a STRAY cat!");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("You aren't a cat?");
            // Some sort of loop here requesting input again?

        }
    }
}
```

That is an example of my current code

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: Put the valid responses into a `List` of some kind, then use `List#contains` to test of the response from the user is within the `List` or not.  Otherwise you will have a very long exit condition with a bunch of OR conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it with a `List`. Note the use of `String.Join()` so that your options in the output would automatically be updated if you changed the List:

```
import java.util.*;
class Main { 
    
  public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String pBackg;
    List<String> options = Arrays.asList("DOMESTIC", "CLAN", "STRAY");
    boolean valid = false;
    do {
      System.out.println("");
      System.out.println("Please type your Cat's BACKGROUND!");
      System.out.println("Your options are:");
      System.out.println(String.join(" / ", options));
      System.out.print("Background: ");
      pBackg = input.nextLine().toUpperCase().trim();
      valid = (options.indexOf(pBackg) != -1);
      if (!valid) {
        System.out.println("You aren't a cat?");
      }
    } while (!valid);
    System.out.println("You're a " + pBackg + " cat!");
  }
  
}
```

Sample run:

```
Please type your Cat's BACKGROUND!
Your options are:
DOMESTIC / CLAN / STRAY
Background: feral
You aren't a cat?

Please type your Cat's BACKGROUND!
Your options are:
DOMESTIC / CLAN / STRAY
Background: tacos are great
You aren't a cat?

Please type your Cat's BACKGROUND!
Your options are:
DOMESTIC / CLAN / STRAY
Background: clan
You're a CLAN cat!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Please type your Cat's BACKGROUND!:");
    System.out.println("Your options are:");
    System.out.println("DOMESTIC / CLAN / STRAY");
    String pBackg = input.nextLine();

    ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("DOMESTIC", "CLAN", "STRAY"));

    // Updated code
    while (!options.contains(pBackg)) {
       System.out.println("You aren't a cat?");
       pBackg = input.nextLine();
    }

    switch (pBackg) {
        case "DOMESTIC":
            System.out.println("You're a DOMESTIC cat!");
            break;
        case "CLAN":
            System.out.println("You're a CLAN cat!");
            break;
        case "STRAY":
            System.out.println("You're a STRAY cat!");
            break;
        default:
    }

}
```

This is generalizable for if you have a lot of options and a list of all the options that you want to check input for.

Alternatively remember that `while` loops have a condition that takes in any boolean value. What you mentioned

> loop until pBackg is DOMESTIC

is basically end loop if `pBackg.equals("DOMESTIC")`. We want to continue loop if it isn't, so we reverse the condition using `!`. You can check multiple conditions by using && (and). So another way of doing what you want would be

```
while (!pBackg.equals("DOMESTIC") && !pBackg.equals("CLAN") && !pBackg.equals("STRAY")) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: That `while` loop will not read the input again and loop forever since it will not enter the block if the input is not in the list.

Comment: Ah I see, you're correct it is not correct since it would not print out a line, but I'm not sure where you're seeing an infinite loop if you would like to point that out for me.

Comment: you are right, it was not an infinite loop, my mistake.